# Dockerizing a command line application

Tags: php, docker, symfony, docker-compose

I have created a command line application using symfony 3.4 which doesn't need to display any web page.

I generally run the commands like following:

```
php bin/console MY_COMMAND_NAME
```

I want to dockerize the application and share it with others, so inside the root directory of my project I created a **docker-compose.yml** file, which looks like following:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
    web:
        image: php:7.3-cli
```

Then I ran docker-compose up, after that I checked the PHP version by the following command and it showed my the correct version:

```
docker run php:7.3-cli php -v
```

However, when I ran **docker ps**, it didn't show any container running.

My question is how to run the commands inside my project root directory. FYI, I am using Docker Toolbox, on windows 10 Home Edition and my project location is:

```
C:\Users\{my_user_name}\Desktop\folder_1\folder_2
```

Comment: The docker container need to have a long running process defined in [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) to stay running. `php-cli` is not that.

Comment: You need a `docker run -v` option or a Docker Compose `volumes:` option to mount host directory content into the container for it to be visible.

Comment: @DavidMaze. I am very new docker. Could you please show me how my docker-compose.yml file should look like then ?

Answer (score 0):

The docker container need to have a long running process defined in [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) to stay running. php-cli is not that. If you run `composer up`, you'll see something like this:

```
$ docker-compose up

Creating network "tempphpdocker_default" with the default driver
Pulling web (php:7.3-cli)...
7.3-cli: Pulling from library/php
b8f262c62ec6: Pull complete
a98660e7def6: Pull complete
4d75689ceb37: Pull complete
639eb0368afa: Pull complete
2cdbfdb779b1: Pull complete
e0b637fa9606: Pull complete
da7333b0ef25: Pull complete
01d65ff46009: Pull complete
673e50bed3b9: Pull complete
bf6c6e34305d: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:1453f5ef0d4d1d424ed8114dd90a775bdec06cc6fb3bbae9521dcb4ca0c8ca90
Status: Downloaded newer image for php:7.3-cli
Creating tempphpdocker_web_1 ... 
Creating tempphpdocker_web_1 ... done
Attaching to tempphpdocker_web_1
web_1  | Interactive shell
web_1  | 
tempphpdocker_web_1 exited with code 0
```

The exit code is 0. This means your command in the docker image `php:7.3-cli` has successfully run and finished.

To properly dockerize your applicaiton, you should override this by writing you own docker file with proper [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) calls that bundle your CLI program into it. Your `Dockerfile` should probably look something like this:

```
FROM php:7.3-cli

RUN mkdir -p /opt/workdir/bin
RUN mkdir -p /opt/workdir/vendor

COPY bin/ /opt/workdir/bin
COPY vendor/ /opt/workdir/vendor

WORKDIR /opt/workdir
CMD php ./bin/console COMMAND
```

You can simply build and run this `Dockerfile`, or you if you prefer `docker-compose`, you can define `docker-compose.yml` in the same folder as the Dockerfile:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
    web:
        image: php-custom
        build: ./
```

Please noted that a dockerized application can only access files and folder in the docker image. You should bind [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) of your local file system to the container before it can actually work on your filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty fix to keep you container running just override the container command in docker-compose.

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  web:
    image: php:7.3-cli
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```

when you run `docker-compose up` it will keep the docker container but it will do not thing, just will give away to **run command inside container**.

```
docker exec -it php-cli_web_1 ash
```

> My question is how to run the commands inside my project root
>   directory.

As mentioned by @David, you need to mount your host project to the container in docker-compose.

For instance

your project is placed on the host `/home/myporject`, mount the project within docker-compose and it will be available inside the container. then you can update the command of your docker-compose to run the script.

keep in mind

**The life of container is the life of docker-compose command**

When the execution completed your container will be die after execution. so your container will run until the `php:7.3-cli /app/your_script.php` this script completed.

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  web:
    image: php:7.3-cli
    command: php:7.3-cli /app/your_script.php
    volumes:
      - /home/myporject:/app
```